# How can I change the SOLR icon displayed?

Tags: solr

We have several instances of SOLR which correspond to different releases and/or production levels.  However, all SOLR icons display the same traditional red-starburst.  I would like to be able to modify this icon to be different for different production levels (e.g. red, yellow, or green, not just red).

There doesn't seem to be a publicly exposed resource to manage this.

Comment: Are you thinking of the favicon displayed to the left in the tab in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the favicon displayed by replacing the `favicon.ico` file located under the `server/solr-webapp/webapp/img` directory inside your Solr home directory.

You can use ImageMagick (`convert`), most image editors or an online service like [convertico - png to ico](https://convertico.com) to get your image file in the correct format.